# can ROS2 be installed with Ubuntu 22.10?

Tags: software-installation

Hi I have trouble to install ROS2 on Ubuntu 22.10 , code name: Kinetic Kudu, can your expertise please give me any advice on how to set up ROS2 on Ubuntu 22.10?
thanks

Comment: FYI:  You are aware the warning notices on the approaching EOL of Ubuntu 22.10 are already out (eg. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/14/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-20-2023/) so why set up something on a release that's near it's final days?

Answer (score 2):

Apart from guiverc's comment, it's evident that ROS2 is intended to be installed on [Ubuntu LTS releases](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html) - the current being Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish).

> Debian packages for ROS 2 Rolling Ridley are currently available for Ubuntu Jammy.

Can you install it on 22.10? Maybe it will work. Is it a good idea? Probably not, since 22.10 will be out of support in less than a month.

The advice is: Use 22.04 LTS for ROS2 applications.